# how to make PdfView with side preview and main view

Tags: ios, swift, pdfview, iosdeployment

[image]

Same as above screen i want to show Pdf document in two lanes.
I have tried `displayMode` property of pdfview but not find any desired solution.

Comment: What's the specific challenge? Is it how you do you design this UI or something specific to the PDFKit?

Comment: i want to display same pdf like above, thumbnails left side, and Doument right side, if i select any page from thumbnails then particular that page will be focused

Comment: @JagveerSingh You can create CollectionView with image (thumbnail) of each page

Comment: JagveerSingh Does @B2Fq 's comment help?

Comment: it doesnt help in some sense but it gives alternate to solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the solution to read and display the pdf doc in a view, all you need, is to have another layout where you would be reading the pdfs and generate thumbnails of it. This layout could be a UITableView or UICollectionView.
On tap of these thumbnails, you would open the respective pdf in the detail View on the right.

The side bar view (collection/table view on the left) and the detail view both can be backed by a single controller (added as subviews) or could be backed by separate view controllers added to and maintained by a container View (both will be added as childviewcontroller ref:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller). The choice of the design is upto you depending on how much work the controller got to do.